# jquery showing totally wrong

Tags: jquery, slider

Got an issue with a jquery slider and it seems that I can't get it right.

The slider shows correctly while I edit it on my pc, however when I uploaded the website it shows totally wrong.

I tried different things in CSS. However I'm completely stuck and the website looks all wrong.

Please have a look at [this](http://www.northwind.cwahi.net)

```
/* Header Scroll */

.nivoSlider { position:relative;}
.nivoSlider img { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;}
.nivoSlider a.nivo-imageLink { position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:0; padding:0; margin:0; z-index:60; display:none;}
.nivo-slice { display:block; position:absolute; z-index:50; height:100%; }
.nivo-caption { position:absolute; left:0px; bottom:0px;  color:#000; width:100%; z-index:89; padding-left: 10px; font-weight: bold}
.nivo-caption p { padding:10px 5px; margin:0;}
.nivo-directionNav a {position:absolute; width:45px; height: 60px; top:45%; z-index:99; cursor:pointer; text-indent:-9999%;}
.nivo-prevNav { background-position: left bottom; left:20px; background:url(images/top_left.png) no-repeat;}
.nivo-nextNav { background-position: left top; right: 0px; background:url(images/top_right.png) no-repeat;}
.nivo-controlNav { bottom:-20px; position:absolute; right:0;}
.nivo-controlNav a { float:left; width:14px; height:14px; display:block; position:relative; z-index:99; cursor:pointer; text-indent:-9999%; background:url(images/scroll_small.png) no-repeat scroll right top;}
.nivo-controlNav a.active { background-position:left top; margin-top:-1px;}
```

Comment: a bunch of your javascript files aren't loading. that is probably why.

Comment: And how can i fix that ?any solution ?

Comment: When you run your website are three any error or warning messages showing up in your browser's debugger tool console?

Answer (score 1):

http://northwind.cwahi.net/lib/jquery.custom.js
encoding is a mess. Try re-uploading with different file-transfer-type.

**Code**

```
//nivoSlider call ----------------------------------------------------
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.waveshow').nivoSlider({
        effect:'sliceDown',
        slices:15,
        animSpeed:1000,
        pauseTime:5000,
        directionNav:true, //Next & Prev
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
        controlNav:false, //1,2,3...
        keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover:true, //Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){} //Triggers after all slides have been shown
    });
});



//Wave slider function -------------------------------------------------------------

(function($) {

    $.fn.nivoSlider = function(options) {

        //Defaults are below
        var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.nivoSlider.defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            //Useful variables. Play carefully.
            var vars = {
                currentSlide: 0,
                currentImage: '',
                totalSlides: 0,
                randAnim: '',
                running: false,
                paused: false,
                stop:false
            };

            //Get this slider
            var slider = $(this);
            slider.data('nivo:vars', vars);
            slider.css('position','relative');
            slider.width('1px');
            slider.height('1px');
            slider.addClass('nivoSlider');

            //Find our slider children
            var kids = slider.children();
            kids.each(function() {
                var child = $(this);
                if(!child.is('img')){
                    if(child.is('a')){
                        child.addClass('nivo-imageLink');
                    }
                    child = child.find('img:first');
                }
                //Don't ask
                var childWidth = child.width();
                if(childWidth == 0) childWidth = child.attr('width');
                var childHeight = child.height();
                if(childHeight == 0) childHeight = child.attr('height');
                //Resize the slider
                if(childWidth > slider.width()){
                    slider.width(childWidth);
                }
                if(childHeight > slider.height()){
                    slider.height(childHeight);
                }
                child.css('display','none');
                vars.totalSlides++;
            });

            //Get initial image
            if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){
                vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
            } else {
                vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
            }

            //Show initial link
            if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){
                $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');
            }

            //Set first background
            slider.css('background','url('+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +') no-repeat');

            //Add initial slices
            for(var i = 0; i < settings.slices; i++){
                var sliceWidth = Math.round(slider.width()/settings.slices);
                if(i == settings.slices-1){
                    slider.append(
                        $('<div class="nivo-slice"></div>').css({ left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px', width:(slider.width()-(sliceWidth*i))+'px' })
                    );
                } else {
                    slider.append(
                        $('<div class="nivo-slice"></div>').css({ left:(sliceWidth*i)+'px', width:sliceWidth+'px' })
                    );
                }
            }

            //Create caption
            slider.append(
                $('<div class="nivo-caption"><p></p></div>').css({ display:'none', opacity:settings.captionOpacity })
            );          
            //Process initial  caption
            if(vars.currentImage.attr('title') != ''){
                $('.nivo-caption p', slider).html(vars.currentImage.attr('title'));                 
                $('.nivo-caption', slider).fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
            }

            //In the words of Super Mario "let's a go!"
            var timer = 0;
            if(!settings.manualAdvance){
                timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
            }

            //Add Direction nav
            if(settings.directionNav){
                slider.append('<div class="nivo-directionNav"><a class="nivo-prevNav">Prev</a><a class="nivo-nextNav">Next</a></div>');

                //Hide Direction nav
                if(settings.directionNavHide){
                    $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                    slider.hover(function(){
                        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).show();
                    }, function(){
                        $('.nivo-directionNav', slider).hide();
                    });
                }

                $('a.nivo-prevNav', slider).live('click', function(){
                    if(vars.running) return false;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = '';
                    vars.currentSlide-=2;
                    nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
                });

                $('a.nivo-nextNav', slider).live('click', function(){
                    if(vars.running) return false;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = '';
                    nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
                });
            }

            //Add Control nav
            if(settings.controlNav){
                var nivoControl = $('<div class="nivo-controlNav"></div>');
                slider.append(nivoControl);
                for(var i = 0; i < kids.length; i++){
                    nivoControl.append('<a class="nivo-control" rel="'+ i +'">'+ (i + 1) +'</a>');
                }
                //Set initial active link
                $('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass('active');

                $('.nivo-controlNav a', slider).live('click', function(){
                    if(vars.running) return false;
                    if($(this).hasClass('active')) return false;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = '';
                    slider.css('background','url('+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +') no-repeat');
                    vars.currentSlide = $(this).attr('rel') - 1;
                    nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'control');
                });
            }

            //Keyboard Navigation
            if(settings.keyboardNav){
                $(window).keypress(function(event){
                    //Left
                    if(event.keyCode == '37'){
                        if(vars.running) return false;
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        timer = '';
                        vars.currentSlide-=2;
                        nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'prev');
                    }
                    //Right
                    if(event.keyCode == '39'){
                        if(vars.running) return false;
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        timer = '';
                        nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, 'next');
                    }
                });
            }

            //For pauseOnHover setting
            if(settings.pauseOnHover){
                slider.hover(function(){
                    vars.paused = true;
                    clearInterval(timer);
                    timer = '';
                }, function(){
                    vars.paused = false;
                    //Restart the timer
                    if(timer == '' && !settings.manualAdvance){
                        timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
                    }
                });
            }

            //Event when Animation finishes
            slider.bind('nivo:animFinished', function(){ 
                vars.running = false; 
                //Hide child links
                $(kids).each(function(){
                    if($(this).is('a')){
                        $(this).css('display','none');
                    }
                });
                //Show current link
                if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('a')){
                    $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).css('display','block');
                }
                //Restart the timer
                if(timer == '' && !vars.paused && !settings.manualAdvance){
                    timer = setInterval(function(){ nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, false); }, settings.pauseTime);
                }
                //Trigger the afterChange callback
                settings.afterChange.call(this);
            });
        });

        function nivoRun(slider, kids, settings, nudge){
            //Get our vars
            var vars = slider.data('nivo:vars');
            if(vars.stop) return false;

            //Trigger the beforeChange callback
            settings.beforeChange.call(this);

            //Set current background before change
            if(!nudge){
                slider.css('background','url('+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +') no-repeat');
            } else {
                if(nudge == 'prev'){
                    slider.css('background','url('+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +') no-repeat');
                }
                if(nudge == 'next'){
                    slider.css('background','url('+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +') no-repeat');
                }
            }
            vars.currentSlide++;
            if(vars.currentSlide == vars.totalSlides){ 
                vars.currentSlide = 0;
                //Trigger the slideshowEnd callback
                settings.slideshowEnd.call(this);
            }
            if(vars.currentSlide < 0) vars.currentSlide = (vars.totalSlides - 1);
            //Set vars.currentImage
            if($(kids[vars.currentSlide]).is('img')){
                vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]);
            } else {
                vars.currentImage = $(kids[vars.currentSlide]).find('img:first');
            }

            //Set acitve links
            if(settings.controlNav){
                $('.nivo-controlNav a', slider).removeClass('active');
                $('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+ vars.currentSlide +')', slider).addClass('active');
            }

            //Process caption
            if(vars.currentImage.attr('title') != ''){
                if($('.nivo-caption', slider).css('display') == 'block'){
                    $('.nivo-caption p', slider).fadeOut(settings.animSpeed, function(){
                        $(this).html(vars.currentImage.attr('title'));
                        $(this).fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
                    });
                } else {
                    $('.nivo-caption p', slider).html(vars.currentImage.attr('title'));
                }                   
                $('.nivo-caption', slider).fadeIn(settings.animSpeed);
            } else {
                $('.nivo-caption', slider).fadeOut(settings.animSpeed);
            }

            //Set new slice backgrounds
            var  i = 0;
            $('.nivo-slice', slider).each(function(){
                var sliceWidth = Math.round(slider.width()/settings.slices);
                $(this).css({ height:'0px', opacity:'0', 
                    background: 'url('+ vars.currentImage.attr('src') +') no-repeat -'+ ((sliceWidth + (i * sliceWidth)) - sliceWidth) +'px 0%' });
                i++;
            });

            if(settings.effect == 'random'){
                var anims = new Array("sliceDownRight","sliceDownLeft","sliceUpRight","sliceUpLeft","sliceUpDown","sliceUpDownLeft","fold","fade");
                vars.randAnim = anims[Math.floor(Math.random()*(anims.length + 1))];
                if(vars.randAnim == undefined) vars.randAnim = 'fade';
            }

            //Run effects
            vars.running = true;
            if(settings.effect == 'sliceDown' || settings.effect == 'sliceDownRight' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceDownRight' ||
                settings.effect == 'sliceDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceDownLeft'){
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider);
                if(settings.effect == 'sliceDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceDownLeft') slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider).reverse();
                slices.each(function(){
                    var slice = $(this);
                    slice.css('top','0px');
                    if(i == settings.slices-1){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished'); });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    i++;
                });
            } 
            else if(settings.effect == 'sliceUp' || settings.effect == 'sliceUpRight' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpRight' ||
                    settings.effect == 'sliceUpLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpLeft'){
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider);
                if(settings.effect == 'sliceUpLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpLeft') slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider).reverse();
                slices.each(function(){
                    var slice = $(this);
                    slice.css('bottom','0px');
                    if(i == settings.slices-1){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished'); });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    i++;
                });
            } 
            else if(settings.effect == 'sliceUpDown' || settings.effect == 'sliceUpDownRight' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpDown' || 
                    settings.effect == 'sliceUpDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpDownLeft'){
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                var v = 0;
                var slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider);
                if(settings.effect == 'sliceUpDownLeft' || vars.randAnim == 'sliceUpDownLeft') slices = $('.nivo-slice', slider).reverse();
                slices.each(function(){
                    var slice = $(this);
                    if(i == 0){
                        slice.css('top','0px');
                        i++;
                    } else {
                        slice.css('bottom','0px');
                        i = 0;
                    }

                    if(v == settings.slices-1){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished'); });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ height:'100%', opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    v++;
                });
            } 
            else if(settings.effect == 'fold' || vars.randAnim == 'fold'){
                var timeBuff = 0;
                var i = 0;
                $('.nivo-slice', slider).each(function(){
                    var slice = $(this);
                    var origWidth = slice.width();
                    slice.css({ top:'0px', height:'100%', width:'0px' });
                    if(i == settings.slices-1){
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ width:origWidth, opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed, '', function(){ slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished'); });
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    } else {
                        setTimeout(function(){
                            slice.animate({ width:origWidth, opacity:'1.0' }, settings.animSpeed);
                        }, (100 + timeBuff));
                    }
                    timeBuff += 50;
                    i++;
                });
            }  
            else if(settings.effect == 'fade' || vars.randAnim == 'fade'){
                var i = 0;
                $('.nivo-slice', slider).each(function(){
                    $(this).css('height','100%');
                    if(i == settings.slices-1){
                        $(this).animate({ opacity:'1.0' }, (settings.animSpeed*2), '', function(){ slider.trigger('nivo:animFinished'); });
                    } else {
                        $(this).animate({ opacity:'1.0' }, (settings.animSpeed*2));
                    }
                    i++;
                });
            }
        }
    };

    //Default settings
    $.fn.nivoSlider.defaults = {
        effect:'random',
        slices:15,
        animSpeed:500,
        pauseTime:3000,
        directionNav:true,
        directionNavHide:true,
        controlNav:true,
        keyboardNav:true,
        pauseOnHover:true,
        manualAdvance:false,
        captionOpacity:0.8,
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){}
    };

    $.fn.reverse = [].reverse;

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank u guys, was indeed the custome file. just replced the "wave slide" by "nivoslider" and all goes smoothly. HAPPY NEW YEAR !

Comment: @Alice: If this answer helped you solve your problem mark it as accepted please. If it did not then please post your solution as an answer and mark that one as accepted instead.